# Avaya CTI query

Tags: apex, cti

My requirement is to pop the screens mentioned  in CTI settings  based on the phone number the call is coming from and not the IVR extension it is being transferred from.

Is it something that can be implemented through any settings or needs to be done through code ?

If through code , can you please give an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented ScreenPop by javascript, the coding is

`if (jsonObj["eventtype"]=='offer') {
    // agent is not idle
    myAgentIdle = false;
    // inbound screen pop
    if (jsonObj["origcalling"]) {
        document.getElementById('txtCLI').value = jsonObj["origcalling"];
        document.getElementById('txtDNIS').value = jsonObj["called"];
        sforce.interaction.searchAndScreenPop(jsonObj["origcalling"], '',
            'inbound', searchAndScreenPopCallback);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('txtCLI').value = jsonObj["calling"];
        document.getElementById('txtDNIS').value = jsonObj["called"];
        sforce.interaction.searchAndScreenPop(jsonObj["calling"], '',
            'inbound', searchAndScreenPopCallback);
    }
}`

My page has the programming details, you can check the URL below

https://upinget.wordpress.com/2016/08/13/ctisvr-open-cti/

Comment: thanks . I have another question here about CTI . Please take a look .http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137885/avaya-cti-screen-pop-to-vf-page-query

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe for the call delivered event, in case the station is call observed and a call is alerting at the users station a notification is provided containg all relevant CTI data. 
Usually the caller number is stored in the *callingDevice* attribute, which is a mandatory attribute, but in case the call goes through an IVR this is overwrittten - and the customer caller number is located in the *originalCallInfo* optional parameter - which is an Avaya properietary attribute.

**Delivered Event**

Event: CSTADeliveredEvent

ServiceParameters: *monitorCrossRefID, connection, alertingDevice,
callingDevice, calledDevice, lastRedirectionDevice,
localConnectionInfo, cause*

Private Parameters: *deliveredType, trunk, trunkGroup, trunkMember, split,
lookaheadInfo, userEnteredCode, userInfo, reason, originalCallInfo,
distributingDevice, distributingVDN, ucid, callOriginatorInfo,
flexibleBilling, deviceHistory*

*orignialCallInfo*: [optional] Specifies the original call information. 
Note that information is not repeated in the *originalCallInfo*, if it is already reported in the CSTA service parameters or in the private data. For example, the *callingDevice* and *calledDevice* in the *originalCallInfo* will be *NULL* if the *callingDevice* and the *calledDevice* in the CSTA service parameters are the original calling and called devices. Only when the original devices are different from the most recent *callingDevice* and *calledDevice*, the *callingDevice* and *calledDevice* in the *originalCallInfo* will be set.

There are reliable solutions out there that are Avaya DevConnect certified and also Salesforce security reviewed that already have this intelligence, one out of the many is Desktop Connect - a Geomant product.

You can find out more [here](https://www.geomant.com/end-user-solutions/desktop-connect) or on [App Exchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4I1HEAV)